# JList doesn't display new added element from my combobox

Tags: java, swing, list, combobox, jlist

I created combobox which get elements from `DefaultListModel` in another class. However, when ever I click an item from my combobox it doesn't add the item elements to my `Jlist`.

Comment: 1) Don't use mouseClicked. You will not generated a click if the mouse moves even a pixel between the mousePressed and mouseReleased events. Use either mousePressed or mouseReleased. 2) If that doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell what is happening based on your few random lines of code. Also add some debug statements to your code to see exactly what code is being executed. Is your "if condition" true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding your `MouseListener` to `JList`. But expecting when an item selected from combobox fire that `actionPerformed`.

> However, when ever I click an item from my combobox it doesn't add the
>   item elements to my Jlist

The code which adding `MouseListener` to `JList`:

```
courseList = new JList(list);   
courseList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        String selectedValue = (String) mealsCombo.getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedValue.equals("Main")){
            list.addElement("Main");
        }
    }
});
```

So add the mouse listener to your combobox. Actually an `ActionListener` or an `ItemListener` could be better.

Comment: I copied the code from my `Jlist` into my `combobox`. I updated the code above on my post. I also  added a `ActionListener`. However, now it adds the name menu into my Jlist but the elements in my Jlist @rdonuk

Comment: `super.addElement(new itemList());` this line is odd. What do you expecting with this? Why are you creating itemlist in here?

Comment: this huge help thank you ,but this is still not showing the price and kcal for each item in the Jlist

Comment: Check the `Meal` class. In `toString` you can decide which text will be shown in `JList` for each meal. For example if you return `Name + " " + Kcal` in `toString`, kcal will be appear.